# How to find Maximal Matching for non bipartite graph in polynomial time?

Tags: algorithm, max, matching, bipartite, network-flow

I know we can use Ford Fulkerson Algorithm of network flow to find Maximum matching in Bipartite graph. But is there any **algorithm which uses network flow concept and gives maximum(or even maximal) matching for a non-bipartite graph**?

Comment: See [Lecture Notes on Non-Bipartite Matching](http://www-math.mit.edu/~goemans/18433S09/matching-nonbip-notes.pdf).

Comment: I have read blossom algorithm. But it doesn't seem to use the concept of network flow as far as I understood.
please correct me if I am wrong?
Is there any way to solve this problem like we do for bipartite graphs?
Maybe by assigning the weight of 1 to every edge and find a flow. 
And then consider alternate edges?